# fptw64.exe -closemnf issue

Tags: windows, operating-system, bios

under windows,type command "fptw64.exe -closemnf",it will fail.

error 683: Get SPI MMIO failed
error 683: Get SPI MMIO failed
error 64: Failed to initialize SPI interface

Dose anyone know how to fix the issue?

Thanks a lot!!!

I tried to search related articles and compared code base and release BIOS version,but I have no idea how to solve